# Is it possible to see the previous contents in a word file?

Tags: software, microsoft

I have a word document where I have turned off the tracking history so technically no one could track my previous changes.  What if I send the word document via email? Could someone possibly use a software tool to do so?

Comment: If I remember correctly the old doc format had a quick save function so for small modifications where not the whole file was written but only some changes appended at the end. So in this format it may be possible to recover a few minor changes. But docx is totally different, and PCs got a lot faster so I don't know if MS designed something similar for docx.

Comment: There's some insight given in the specification found here: https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-DOCX/%5bMS-DOCX%5d.pdf

If you elaborate on your concern a bit, then I can tell you specifically what is or isn't possible per the spec. Had written an answer and now removed as I may have been a little quick with assumptions about your reason(s) for asking and extent to which history would be saved in your perceived worst case scenario.

Comment: This might be answered on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/1562130/can-people-see-the-changes-made-in-word-document

Comment: @Robert indeed, but they were removed in Office 2003 SP3.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert mentions in the comments, once upon a time, Word had a feature called "fast saves" that added the changes at the end of the document, thus allowing someone to recover an earlier version of the document.

The last version with “fast save” was Word 2003. It was no longer available in [Word 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20120428090912/https://www.microsystems.com/resources/wordtips/wordtip023.php), and also removed in [Office 2003 SP3.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/does-word-2010-have-a-quick-save-like-the-one-in/463ab4ce-be8d-40a5-918b-82ff8950bd73)

Modern editors will simply rewrite the whole document. As you state tracking changes is disabled, there will be no history int the document. Those receiving a copy won't be able to "undo" your changes. But if you're specially wary, you could select the whole document, copy and paste it into a new file, so that it appears as a single change. Or you could even open the contents of the docx file (it actually follows zip format) and inspect the xml files with the contents, in order to ensure there are no leakages.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. If I copy a content of a file and paste it somewhere else, the file size is different, why? I have created two test dates by writing hello in both with the same font and this also has different file sizes and (bytes)

Comment: @Lisa there is some included metadata, such as the time you made it (so the actual contents will be slightly different), and that's then compressed. A difference of a few bytes up or down would be expected. If it's something larger, there may be some feature in one of the documents (such a footer), but I would have to look at the actual files.